# Error con función lambda dentro de comando M.col en Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Antes de todo decir que apenas llevo 2 días trabajando con Python, por lo que soy un novato total, anque me manejo en Matlab y VisualBasic. Al grano:

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el código que se encuentra en el apartado "Three Layer Solution" de esta web: [Elastic Layer Analysis (ELA)](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Elastic-Layer-Analysis-(ELA)#three-layer-solution). Por ahora lo he conseguido con la primera parte, pero hay unas líneas en las que me aparece un error que no comprendo. Estas líneas son:

```
M11=Matrix([[a02,b02,c02,d02],
        [a03,b03,c03,d03],
        [a04,b04,c04,d04],
        [a05,b05,c05,d05]])

M11.col(0,lambda i,j: i*exp(-xi*h[0]))
M11.col(1,lambda i,j: i*exp(xi*h[0]))
M11.col(2,lambda i,j: i*exp(-xi*h[0]))
M11.col(3,lambda i,j: i*exp(xi*h[0]))
```

Y el error que recibo es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: col() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Si hago lo mismo con una matriz M de elementos constantes y cambio el comando M.Col de forma que haga otra operación diferente (por ejemplo lo de aquí debajo), recibo el mismo error.

```
M=Matrix([[1,2,1,2],
         [5,5,5,7],
         [2,2,2,2],
         [1,1,2,2]])

M.col(0,lambda i,j: i*j)
```

He probado mil cosas y ya no sé que hacer. ¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el error? Si más no, ¿podría alguien explicarme qué es lo hace el comando "M11.col(0,lambda i,j: i*exp(-xi *h[0]))"?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tutorial está basado en una versión antigua de SymPy, creo que a partir de la 0.7.3 si no me equivoco los métodos `col` y `row` pasaron a ser solo  selectores:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> help(sympy.Matrix.col)
Help on function col in module sympy.matrices.common:
col(self, j)
    Elementary column selector.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy import eye
    >>> eye(2).col(0)
    Matrix([
    [1],
    [0]])

    See Also
    ========

    row
    col_op
    col_swap
    col_del
    col_join
    col_insert
```

mientras que aparecieron `col_op` y `row_op` que permiten aplicar una función a una determinada columna/fila de la matriz:

```
>>> help(sympy.Matrix.col_op)
Help on function col_op in module sympy.matrices.dense:

col_op(self, j, f)
    In-place operation on col j using two-arg functor whose args are
    interpreted as (self[i, j], i).

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy.matrices import eye
    >>> M = eye(3)
    >>> M.col_op(1, lambda v, i: v + 2*M[i, 0]); M
    Matrix([
    [1, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]])

    See Also
    ========
    col
    row_op
```

Usando tu propio ejemplo:

```
>>> from sympy import Matrix

>>> M = Matrix([[1, 2, 1, 2],
                [5, 5, 5, 7],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [1, 1, 2, 2]])

>>> M.col_op(0, lambda i, j: i * j)
>>> M
Matrix([
[0, 2, 1, 2],
[5, 5, 5, 7],
[4, 2, 2, 2],
[3, 1, 2, 2]])
```

El método `col_op` recibe como primer argumento el índice de la columna sobre la que aplicar la función y como segundo la función propiamente dicha. La función (no tiene por qué ser una función anónima) recibe dos argumentos, `i` que es el valor del elemento y `j` que es el índice de la fila a la que pertenece, el retorno de la función es el nuevo valor. En el ejemplo anterior solo coge el elemento y lo multiplica por el índice de su fila:

> 1 * 0 = 0
>   5 * 1 = 5
>   2 * 2 = 4
>   1 * 3 = 3